# Is there a way to use hv.archive for Holoviews in Jupyter Lab?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab, holoviews

I am trying to use HoloViews hv.archive function in Jupyter Lab, but no archive is generated when I run the code.

When I run:

```
hv.archive.auto()

df.testplot() # create holoviews plot

hv.archive.contents()

hv.archive.export()
```

I get this: `Javascript Error: IPython is not defined`

When running in Jupyter Notebook I don't get the error and an archive folder is created, but I still can't generate the archived plots.

Any way forward would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Currently [hv.archive()](https://www.holoviews.org/user_guide/Exporting_and_Archiving.html) doesn't work with Jupyter Lab, but it should work with Jupyter Notebook though.**

**See this github issue:** 
https://github.com/holoviz/holoviews/issues/3570

If I run the code below in Jupyter Notebook, it works for me.
**Note: run the code below not all at once, but just part by part.**
Otherwise I think the filesystem can't keep up and you get an error.

```
import holoviews as hv

# you can also choose the bokeh backend, but
# no .svg image will be saved
hv.extension('matplotlib')

# start archiving automatically
hv.archive.auto()

# create a simple plot
hv.Curve(range(0,3))

# check contents of current archive
hv.archive.contents()

# export archive to disk
hv.archive.export()

# check status of export
hv.archive.last_export_status()

# recreate simple plot from archive    
import os
from holoviews.core.io import Unpickler
path = os.path.join(hv.archive.notebook_name, 'Curve.hvz')

if os.path.isfile(path):
    obj = Unpickler.load(open(path,"rb"))
    print(obj)

obj
```

This is **what my archive looks like** when exported to disk:

[image: hv archive export to disk]

**More info** on archiving can be found here:
http://holoviews.org/user_guide/Exporting_and_Archiving.html